# map xml value to struct value

Tags: c, xml, struct, xml-parsing, xml-serialization

Can you please help in mapping xml values to a structure member. Suppose if struct abc has data member then it should be like abc.data = myxml.data , where myxml is an xml file which has data attribute value. I have used libxml2 to parse and get those values, but how do I map C struct and XML values. Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to do it manually, by checking tag names and then setting the values in their places.

One way of making it more automated, might be to have a table containing tag names and e.g. `void` pointer pointing to the structure members. Then when you have a tag you can loop over the table comparing the names to the actual tag, and then with some type casting set the value.

Comment: So is it like create a hash table and pass the tags attributes of xml into the table. later loop through the table to retrieve those values. Please let me know if my understanding is correct.

Comment: @user1425941 Something like that yes.